# CheckBox DataTriggers

Tags: wpf

I have the below two checkboxes with datatriggers. If I click combo1, it will uncheck combo2 as expected, but combo1 will not become checked till it is clicked again. This is the same the other way around. Why is this?

```
<CheckBox Name="cbx1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="1">
    <CheckBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=cbx2}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </CheckBox.Style>
</CheckBox>

<CheckBox Name="cbx2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="2">
    <CheckBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=cbx1}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </CheckBox.Style>
</CheckBox>
```

Comment: @EdPlunkett Check 1, 2 is False (B). Check 2, 1 is False (A), but 2 is also still False. I don't get why it takes two clicks...

Comment: My apologies, I should have tried the code. I'm not sure why the two triggers end up having that effect: My guess is this: 1. Check A. 2. B's trigger puts B in "unchecked" state. 3. Check B. 4. A's trigger puts A in "unchecked" state. 5. B's trigger sees A's state changing to "unchecked", and returns B to its default state -- unchecked. 6. Now both are unchecked, and you can check either one at will and it'll stay that way.

Comment: That's a guess, but it's consistent what your code does, and with what mm8 did to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis. Behaviour seems kind of weird to me but I guess I'll just handle it in code. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your requirement is to allow the user to uncheck both boxes, you can't do this declaratively with triggers, because (*contra* my earlier deranged ravings in comments), when a trigger's condition stops being true, it tries to undo what it previously did.

Here's my guess as to what you're seeing:

1. User checks A.
2. B's trigger responds to the now-current state by putting B in "unchecked" state.
3. User checks B.
4. A's trigger responds to the now-current state by putting A in "unchecked" state.
5. B's trigger sees A's state changing to "unchecked", and returns B to its default state -- unchecked.
6. Now both are unchecked, and the user can check either one at will and it'll stay that way.

If you change the default state to `True` as mm8 suggests, then there's no way to make both unchecked. If you make the default state `False`, it's a struggle to get *anything* checked.

But this works:

```
<CheckBox 
    Name="cbx1" 
    Content="1"
    Tag="{Binding ElementName=cbx2}"
    Checked="twinnedCheckBox_Checked"
    />
<CheckBox 
    Name="cbx2" 
    Content="2"
    Tag="{Binding ElementName=cbx1}"
    Checked="twinnedCheckBox_Checked"
    />
```

Code behind:

```
private void twinnedCheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var self = sender as CheckBox;
    var twin = self.Tag as CheckBox;

    if ((bool)twin.IsChecked)
        twin.IsChecked = false;
}
```

You could trivially write an attached behavior property to set up this [twin behavior](https://motionverse.wordpress.com/2010/04/01/%E2%80%9Cyou-hypocrite-lecteur-%E2%80%93-mon-semblable-mon-frere%E2%80%9D/) in XAML.

---

Update: You can do this in pure XAML with `DataTrigger.EnterActions` and Storyboards:

```
<CheckBox Name="cb3" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="3">
    <CheckBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=cb4}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsChecked"
                                    >
                                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="False" />
                                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </CheckBox.Style>
</CheckBox>

<CheckBox Name="cb4" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="4">
    <CheckBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=cb3}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsChecked"
                                    >
                                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="False" />
                                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </CheckBox.Style>
</CheckBox>
```

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for going to the effort of this. I think I'll just do the code route anyways.

Comment: I have to ask what the significance of the link in 'twin behaviour' is for?? "https://motionverse.wordpress.com/2010/04/01/%E2%80%9Cyou-hypocrite-lecteur-%E2%80%93-mon-semblable-mon-frere%E2%80%9D/"

Comment: Mere whimsy. Sadly it's dead now.

Comment: No yours works, seems I mis-copied it. Really? :/ I was hoping for some significance that I was missing. Anyways, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a setter to both styles to make sure that at least one `CheckBox` is always checked if that's what you want:

```
<CheckBox Name="cbx1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="1">
    <CheckBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=cbx2}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </CheckBox.Style>
</CheckBox>

<CheckBox Name="cbx2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="2">
    <CheckBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=cbx1}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </CheckBox.Style>
</CheckBox>
```

Comment: I would like it to be possible to have no checkbox active also.

Comment: Also? You can't have at least one checked and no one checked. This is theoretically impossible.

Comment: Yup definitely impossible. I want one or neither. Your solution is always one 
 active, like a radio button.

Comment: @windowskm You'd have to do that with events.

Comment: @windowskm See my updated answer -- I found a way to do this in pure XAML. It's pretty verbose, but it works.